# Better Practice for Error handling from WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, exception

I have a class library that communicates with my WCF service. The class library can then be used in any of my applications. I am curious as to what would be the best practice in handling the errors. I have thought of two scenarios but wanted to get some feedback from the community. The idea is not only to make sure it's appropriate for .NET solutions, but any other language that might not use the dll but rather call the service directly via a SOAP style call.

Option #1 
Create a result object which will return to the caller API. Such as.

```
Public abstract BaseResponse
{
  [DataMember]
  Public bool IsSuccess { get; set;}
  [DataMember]
  Public string ErrorMsg { get ;set ;}
 }

 Public GetProductResponse : BaseResponse
 {
    [DataMember]
    Public Product p { get;set;}
 }
```

Option #2 : Throw a SOA Fault and allow the end user handle it however they choose. I could handle it in my API - however a direct call to the service would require that end user to code against the fault and handle it correctly.

Comment: What's a "SOA fault"? Did you mean "SOAP Fault"? Not trying to be funny, since "SOA" is a term with meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

Typically what I end up doing is having a business layer that will throw application specific exceptions.  In the event that I want to expose this as a web service, I'll put a very thin layer on top of that that exposes those business services as WCF services.  This layer will do nothing more than pass calls down to the business layer and return results as DataContract or MessageContract objects.  In this very thin WCF layer, I'll catch exceptions from the business layer and map them to SOAP faults.  This allows any .Net application to consume the business layer directly and catch exceptions as well as .Net or non-.Net applications to consume the web service and catch SOAP faults.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Option 2 (soap faults, WCF FaultContracts) then I am doing an internal service, where I know the client is also WCF, and I can make sure FaultExceptions are handled correctly.

When I am making an external/customer-facing service, I usually use option 1, splitting up my message into a "header" and a "body" and have the header contain an error message. I find this easier for other people to understand when telling them how to use your web service, and easier for non-WCF users to implement.

Both ways are fine really, as any decent SOAP tool for whatever language should handle SOAP faults, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a restful webservice yo could use the http status code. And regardless of the service flavour the error handlers in WCF makes the code substantially more readable since it allows a single try/catch definition for methods.

There is a simple example here http://bit.ly/sCybDO

Answer (score 0):

I would use option #2 every time. Faults are a standardised part of the SOAP specification, so any compliant framework should handle them appropriately. If a client is using a framework that doesn't have built in handling, then they will have to write custom code to do it, but that is the case with option #1 anyway, since they will have to understand your custom error semantics.

Unless there is a really good reason, I would always used the standardised approach - it give you the best chance of interoperability.